# symmetricds pro and registration

Tags: symmetricds

I'm trying to configure a replicated backup database using `SymmetricDS pro v 3.7.23`

I use 2 files : `master.properties` for main database:

```
"external.id=server
engine.name=server
auto.config.registration.svr.sql.script=/symmetric-profile-standard-2- 
tier-config.sql
sync.url=http\://192.168.10.7\:31415/sync/server
group.id=server
db.url=jdbc\:mysql\://localhost/sample2?
tinyInt1isBit\=false&zeroDateTimeBehavior\=convertToNull
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.user=root
registration.url=
db.validation.query=select 1
db.init.sql=
db.password=enc\:JESOMMMaOc2VTccuqUQxWQ\=\=
db.connection.properties="
```

And `slave.proerties` for backup database:

```
"external.id=001
engine.name=client-001
sync.url=http\://192.168.10.13\:31415/sync/client-001
group.id=client
db.url=jdbc\:sqlite\:sample2.sqlite
jobs.synchronized.enable=true
db.driver=org.sqlite.JDBC
db.user=
registration.url=http\://192.168.10.7\:31415/sync/server
db.validation.query=select 1
db.init.sql=
db.password=
db.connection.properties="
```

I did everything else like in User Guide but when I run master and                   then The slave I get an error on the slave side:

> could not contact the registration server using the url provided

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your machines are not able to see each other over http.  From the slave machine can you open a browser and hit the registration url with /ping on the end.  You should receive an http 200 ok response with the word pong.

http://192.168.10.7:31415/sync/server

If this is not accessible in a browser from the slave machine there is a network issue.